# iPhone - Using json framework and facebook framework at a time - help

Tags: iphone, json, facebook

I'm working on iphone application.
I downloaded json framework class from the URL [JSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/tree/master/Classes)

I downloaded Facebook framework from git git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git

after downloading I found that facebook also uses JSON code inside "src" folder. But I found that JSON that I downloaded is different from the JSON in facebook.

Which JSON code do I've to use? how can I reuse the JSON code from FB framework itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you're passing facebook a valid JSON string, it shouldn't matter what json encoding framework you use. Last time I implemented facebook connect, I believe they were just using the json framework (http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/). i'm sure they pulled a snapshot at the time of release and it's likely been updated...it should be a quick test for you to confirm.

Comment: I don't know Facebook guys are too slow in updating their dependencies to latest ones....... I changed Facebook JSON to latest one. But its looking for some methods/files that are not available in latest JSON.

Comment: Were you able to comment out those dependencies and test successfully? I thought all they did was include json.h which is the core framework include.  good luck!

Comment: I removed json framework from facebook code, and before removing i copied some methods from old json to new json. lots of changes i've to do.......

Comment: How did you remove it? I cant open the facebook bundle and see the contents of it

Answer (score 0):

Using Satyam's suggestion I removed the JSON code that comes with Facebook SDK, copying the extra code into out json-frameowrk files.

There are a lot of changes, but it seems(not tested thoroughly) to be working. Here is a link to the updated files I am using if it can be helpful.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29449508/JSON%2BFB.zip